# Cut and copy specific string values to adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel database of company and city names in the same cell, from which I'd like to split off the city names to the adjacent cell where the text was found. I have the city names as an array.

Database looks like:

FINER SURROUNDINGS EL CAJON
FIRST CHOICE PLUMBING CO RAMONA
FRANK GILILLAND CONSTRUCTION SANTA YNEZ
etc

My code so far (very rudimentary):

```
Sub FindCityNames()  
Dim citylist(500) As String  
Dim i, j, k As Integer  
For j = 1 To 500  
citylist(j) = Workbooks("cities.xlsm").Worksheets("City list").Cells(j, 1)  
Next j  
For i = 1 To 500  
Cells.Find(What:=citylist(i), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _  
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _  
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate  
    ActiveRange.Cut  
Next i  
End Sub
```

Which should do the job of finding the string and cutting it but I have no idea how to reference the row in which it was found to choose the paste area.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The Range.Row method looks enough. you can also us Range.Offset. Is there anything more needed that I did not see?

Comment: That seems to work, thanks - however now my Cells.Find method returns with a Runtime 91 (Object variable or with block variable not set) error. Do you know why that would be the case?

Comment: It probably means that Find has found nothing. There are a few flaws in your code. Let me understand something: you want to cut the row in order to paste it at the next row? But then what happens to the old content of the next row?

Comment: Say "FINER SURROUNDINGS EL CAJON" is in cell A1 - my goal is to find "EL CAJON" within the cell, cut it from this cell keeping "FINER SURROUNDINGS" in cell A1, and pasting "EL CAJON" into cell A2.   
In the end I managed to do it via the use of strings but Range.Row did indeed help in determining row references - thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I manage to solve the problem via the use of strings:
Thanks A.S.H. for your assistance!

```
Sub FindCityNames()
Dim citylist(20000) As String
Dim i, j, k, l As Integer
Dim city, company As String
For j = 1 To 20000
citylist(j) = Workbooks("adatformazas2.xlsm").Worksheets("City list").Cells(j, 1)
Next j

For j = 1 To 20000
city = UCase(citylist(j))
l = Len(city)
If l > 0 Then
 With ActiveSheet
 '.Cells(1, 8) = city
  For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
   company = RTrim(.Cells(i, 1))
   R = Right(company, l)
   If R = city Then
    If .Cells(i, 2).Value = "" Then
    .Cells(i, 1) = RTrim(Left(company, Len(company) - l))
    .Cells(i, 2) = city
   End If
   End If
  Next i
 End With
End If
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, especially that you did not need to use Select and copy-paste through the clipboard :). Do the effort to indent your code though, it will give you much more control over your own code :).